# Boot freezes just after loading graphics on Ubuntu 18.10 and Fedora 29

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, boot

Both distros use Gnome, both fail at exactly the same moment in boot process.
Background changes, mouse icon is shown and then everything freezes.

Both distros work when running from live-usb. Problem asserts itself when booting from hdd. I've tried repartitioning.. I am using /boot/efi

Will try to repartition again, as it makes sense that could somehow be the issue.

EDIT (last few lines of boot.log):

```
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started WPA supplicant.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Hostname Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Modem Manager.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Raise network interfaces.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Network Manager.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network.
         Starting OpenVPN service...
         Starting Permit User Sessions...
         Starting Network Manager Wait Online...
         Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Permit User Sessions.
         Starting GNOME Display Manager...
         Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Disk Manager.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started OpenVPN service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Snappy daemon.
         Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
```

EDIT: I found [this answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032639/ubuntu-18-04-stuck-in-boot-after-starting-gnome-display-manager-on-intel-graphic) which helped a lot. However in my case problem doesn't seem to be in the display manager, i've tried gdm gdx and lightdm and all have same issue.

It seems that the problem is likely with the GPU, I've purged nvidia drivers (no effect) and am reinstalling them ATM. If this doesn't work I will try to enforce usage of intel gpu (if that's possible)

Comment: It seems like a video driver error. Look at logs.

Comment: from what I can find online, it seems that this is some kind of kernel issue that's caused by insufficient randomness of the system which can be resolved by moving the mouse and pressing keys. However, in my case mouse doesn't work and keys produce no results. I'm gonna try with 18.04 and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If somebody runs into the same problem:

I've logged in using ubuntu recovery mode, resumed to fully booted state. Using ubuntu additional drivers installed proprietary Nvidia drivers, now everything works!

I've also switched display manager to light-dm but this likely had no impact.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue in `RHEL 7.6` with `gdm 3.28` after `X` authorization. I think this is `gdm` bug.

1. Open second console: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Run `htop`, find `X` process and send `SIGTERM` to it.

   - <kbd>F4</kbd> type `gdm` to find `X` process
   - <kbd>F9</kbd> ⇒ `SIGTERM`
3. `X Window` will autoreload and from the second try `gdm` will work properly.
4. **Optional**: you may want to add these lines to `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` to avoid login screen:

   ```
   AutomaticLogin=username
   AutomaticLoginEnable=True
   ```